# I need to replace a bootsrap class name in nested divs using parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my code structure as below

```
<div id="main-parent">
    <div class="child2">
        <div>
            child2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>child3</div>
    -
    -
    -
    -
    <div class="child-n">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="child-n1 col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5">child n</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here i need to replace classes(col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5) with class(col-sm-12).

just parent child and siblings logic i need to change these classes.

Any idea or solution would be helpful

Comment: try `.parent().find('.col-sm-7.col-sm-push-5')` should find the target and you can use `attr()` to replace class.

Comment: here one problem is in child 2,3 has also have same classes('.col-sm-7.col-sm-push-5')

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: are you target specific or all element with class `.col-sm-7.col-sm-push-5` please add more info what is expected and what have you tried so far

Comment: @guradio Don't use `.attr` to change classes, use `.addClass` and `.removeClass`.

Comment: @Fil replace the classes('.col-sm-7.col-sm-push-5') from nested 'child-n'th div

Comment: @Barmar thanks for correcting :)

Comment: @guradio i need the class to been replaced only in the specific 'div' that has class name 'child-n'

Comment: at which point you want ot change the class names, I mean in a button click or, automatically(when document ready)

Comment: @learner @ Barmar got it covered then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a selector that matches the elements that you want to change. Then use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` to change the classes.

This selector only matches the DIVs with classes `col-sm-7 and`col-sm-push-5`inside the`.child-n`DIV, so the similar classes in`child2`and`child3` will not be affected.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#main-parent .child-n .col-sm-7.col-sm-push-5")
    .removeClass("col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5")
    .addClass("col-sm-12");
});
```

```css
.col-sm-7 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.col-sm-push-5 {
  background-color: green;
}
.col-sm-12 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-parent">
  <div class="child2">
    <div>
      child2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>child3</div>
  <div class="child-n">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="child-n1 col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5">child n</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">Click to change class</button>
```

Comment: i think OP need to clarify this statement `here one problem is in child 2,3 has also have same classes` i assume he wants to target a specific element only

Comment: That's why I have `.child-n` in the selector, it just targets the elements within that child.

Comment: I tried with your logic but it throws null exception,when i went below approach it worked $("#main-parent, .child-n, .col-sm-19, .col-sm-push-5").removeClass("col-sm-19 col-sm-push-5").addClass("col-sm-24");

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the help

Comment: Comma in selector means to find elements that match any of the selectors, it doesn't use them as parent-child.

Comment: I've added a demo showing that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you may be looking for:

```
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5');
const array = Array.prototype.slice.call(divs);

array.forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute('class', 'col-sm-12')
})
```

Because this is a live HTML collection you just have to call `setAttribute` and give it the classes you want and it should update in the DOM.